# How does scala's VectorMap work and how is it different than ListMap?

Tags: scala

How does scala's [VectorMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/VectorMap.html) work? It says that it is constant time for look up.

I think ListMap has to iterate through everything to find an entry. Why would vector map be different?

Is it a hash table combined with a vector, where the hash table will map a key to an index in the vector, which has the entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, yes. It has a regular `Map` inside that maps keys to tuples `(index, value)`, where index is pointing into a `Vector` of (keys), which is only used for in-order access (`.head`, `.tail`, `.last`, `.iterator` etc).